Connecting Airflow to Snowflake account
I am having issue connecting the airflow to Snowflake. I think that the airflow admin GUI has changed a bit. But the main issue, is I am not sure how what is what when it comes account in the connection info.
Should I include the org name? I mean based on the image attached, how should I combine ALB33048, KKTQCVP and CLBB7689? Should I separate them with '.' or '-'?
airflow connection GUI
my snowflake account info
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator
from datetime import datetime

# Define your default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    'retries': 1,
}

dag = DAG(
    'example_snowflake_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule='* * * * *',  # Every Monday at 12 PM
)

# Define the Snowflake SQL command
snowflake_sql = """
    select top 10* from Information_schema.tables
"""



snowflake_task = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id='query_snowflake',
    sql=snowflake_sql,
    conn_id='snowflake_conn_id',
    hook_params={
        "account": "KKTQCVP.CLB87689",
        "warehouse": "COMPUTE_WH",
        "database": "<MY_DATABASE>",
        "region": "us-west",
        "login": "<MY_USERNAME>",
        "password": "<MY_PASSWORD>",
        "role": "ACCOUNTADMIN",
        'schema': '<MY_SCHEMA>',
    },
    dag=dag,
)

I tried the posted methods but they are not working.

Can you try this for account parameter,  account = 'CLBB7689.us-east-1', assuming you are in AWS and US east region and the account is CLBB7689.

you can pass the account information with a hypen:
KKTQCVP-CLB87689

